# ZXing library Reed Solomon example

Tags: zxing, galois-field, reed-solomon

I want to try the `ReedSolomonDecoder` from the ZXing library on the example given on page 10 of [this paper](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/rd/pubs/whp/whp-pdf-files/WHP031.pdf)

Basically, it encodes the message

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

using the generator polynomial

```
x^4 + 15x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 12
```

which results in

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 3, 3, 12, 12
```

I want to decode this in the following manner:

```
int[] data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 3, 3, 12, 12};
GenericGF field = new GenericGF(?, 16, 1);  // what integer should I use for primitive here?
ReedSolomonDecoder decoder = new ReedSolomonDecoder(field);
decoder.decode(data, 4);
```

I don't know how to create a `GenericGF` object from the given generator polynomial. I know that it expects a binary integer representation of the polynomial, but to do that, I would need the polynomial to be in an irreducible form, i.e. all the coefficients to be either 0 or 1. How can I achieve that from this given generator polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to this as well but I think you would want to use
`public static GenericGF AZTEC_PARAM = new GenericGF(0x13, 16, 1);`